# Error response from daemon: bad format for link in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

## Question:

In my gitlab CI my docker-in-docker job fails with the following message

```
Preparing environment

ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: Error response from daemon: bad format for links: 0a9eb5ca3305a308a6d7258a1e294935f90fdc6272ae757900e5f7e4860c70b3:docker:dind (docker.go:757:0s). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

Unfortunately, the URL mentioned does not lead to any explanation or solution. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

The dind service definition was flawed in `.gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
.docker_in_docker:
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker:dind
```

It is not allowed for the alias to contain colons, so it should be `alias: whatever` instead of `alias: badly:shaped`.